# Integral well-defined

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have always had trouble to prove that something is well-defined I never know how to do it. I don't even know what do I have to prove. So I'm studying Lebesgue integration of non-negative functions and although it seems obvious for the author that $ \int f d \lambda $ is well defined, I wish I could understand perfectly why?

The formal definition is: Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0, \infty ]$ is measurable. Then the integral of $f$ is 
$$\int f d \lambda = \sup \left\{ \left. \int s d \lambda \: \right | \: s \leq f, s \in S \right\} $$

Where $\int s d \lambda = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \alpha_{k} \lambda (A_{k}).$

So I want to prove formally that the integral is well-defined. Thanks!

Comment: In the definition you have given, you have a set of nonnegative numbers; the supremum of such a set exists, at least within the extended real numbers. That's all. The difficulty of a Lebesgue integral being well-defined is only when the integrand takes on both signs, in which case the integral may be a $\infty - \infty$ form.

Comment: Additional point: The set j question is **nonempty**. Furthermore, you should check that the new definition of the integral coincides with the old definition for simple functions.

Comment: Are you sure that's what he's referring to? I don't see how the notion of "well-defined" arises in that definition. Now, there's definitely an issue in showing that the integral of a _simple_ function is well-defined. Meaning this: Supposing that $\sum a_j\chi_{E_j}=\sum b_k\chi_{F_k}$, how do you know that $\sum a_j\mu(E_j)=\sum b_k\mu(F_k)$?